# Secure Hadoop - Datanode cannot connect with namenode

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hadoop2

I am using hadoop-2.6.0 and created HA enabled cluster with kerberos security in windows platform. Everything works fine if permission is set to false. But when I enable below property,

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Datanode cannot connect with the namenode. I am getting the following exception

**Exception**

```
2015-05-21 10:44:42,461 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: kumar/192.168.3.4:9000
2015-05-21 10:44:46,079 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: dinesh/192.168.3.3:9000
2015-05-21 10:44:47,471 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: kumar/192.168.3.4:9000
2015-05-21 10:44:51,085 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: dinesh/192.168.3.3:9000
2015-05-21 10:44:52,477 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: kumar/192.168.3.4:9000
```

I cannot find the exact root cause for this problem. I need help to solve this.

Comment: Change `dfs.permissions` to `dfs.permissions.enabled`. `dfs.permissions` is deprecated. Refer https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html

Comment: @RajeshN Both works fine. We can either use dfs.permissions.enabled or dfs.permissions.

Comment: Could you post your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I have not set anything in hosts file. Each host added in the same DNS server. So no need to edit in hosts file.

Comment: @Kumar, try to add your datanode hosts to the hadoop policy

Comment: I didn't mentioned anything about authorization. Anyway i used "*" in all properties in hadoop-policy.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the default supergroup name to newly created group which has members of all hadoop users. Now all user in that group act as superuser hence it works fine.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
    <value>Hadoopgroup</value>
</property>
```

Refer [superuser](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#The_Super-User)